# Directshow,capture two USB webcams, can't start at same time

Tags: video, usb, webcam, directshow, capture

I have two graph in my program each one can control a USB camera to capture video data.

I can start them separately without problem like:

```
cam_a.start();
sleep(100);
cam_b.start();
```

However,without the "**sleep**" the second graph will not execute correctly,like no file writing and no frame display.

Anyone can help to solve this problem?

Win7 64 bits, windows sdk 7
Logitech c210 webcam
Logitech c510 webcam
Directshow video capture.

Comment: Maybe dshow's bug or bug within one of the CAM driver? Can you test your app again with another two different CAMs?

Comment: Or, fake CAM by two file source?

Comment: I can make it work with one DV cam(1394)+usb webcam, or two Dv cams(1394). But if two usb webcams then I must put a delay there.

Comment: Is c210 usb cam? What if two usb cams of other model? I guess the problem maybe the c210 device driver not thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Logitech USB Cams were usually TWAIN/WIA based (http://www.twain.org, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your issue is probably caused by the Logitech TWAIN/WIA driver not being thread safe or having a bug. Your DV-1394 Cam probably uses a diferent driver so there is no colision with the Logitech driver.